# Making the marker size as small as possible with matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphing

My program can generate up to 2000000 points within 5 seconds, so I don't have a problem with speed. Right now I am using matplotlib.pyplot.scatter to scatter all my points on my graph. For `s=1`, it gives me small circles, but not small enough, because it does not show the intricate patterns. When I use `s=0.1`, it gives me this weird marker shape:

[image]

Which makes the marker larger despite me making the size smaller. I have searched all over the internet including stack overflow, but they do not tell how to minimize the size further. Unfortunately, I have to show all the points, and cannot just show a random sample of them.

I have come to the conclusion that matplotlib is made for a small sample of points and not meant for plotting millions of points. However, if it is possible to make the size smaller please let me know.

Anyway, for my points, I have all the x values in order in one array, and all the y values in order in another array. Could someone suggest a graphing package in python I could use to graph all the points in a way that the size would be very small since when I plot the points now it just becomes one big block of color instead of intricate designs forming in the shape as they should be.

Thanks for any help in advance!

---

EDIT: My code that I am using to scatter the points is:

```py
plt.savefig(rootDir+"b"+str(Nvertices)+"_"+str(xscale)+"_"+str(yscale)+"_"+str(phi)+"_"+str(psi)+"_"+CurrentRun+"_color.png", dpi =600)
```

---

EDIT: I got my answer, I added `linewidths = 0` and that significantly reduced the size of the points, giving me what I needed.

Comment: Your question doesn't show any code, so it is hard to guess which parameters you're using.  You might try to remove the boundary line (`lw=0` if you're using `plt.scatter`)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps you can try making the `linewidths` as `0` i.e., the line width of the marker edges. Notice the difference in the two plots below

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 4))
plt.scatter(np.random.rand(100000), np.random.rand(100000), s=0.1)
```

[image]

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 4))
plt.scatter(np.random.rand(100000), np.random.rand(100000), s=0.1, linewidths=0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you this helped so much! This definitely improved my program.

Comment: If you're using `plt.plot`, the solution is to use **`markeredgecolor='none'`** as mentioned by @JohanC in the comments of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63366990/how-do-i-make-small-markers-with-matplotlib).

Comment: If you are editing the Line2D object after it is generated then use child.set_markeredgewidth(0)

Answer (score 2):

you can set the marker to a single pixel using `marker=','` in your call to `scatter`.

See the markers documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html#module-matplotlib.markers)